# Configurar tarea CRON para ejecutar regularmente un archivo guardado en un directorio de Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cron

Estoy intentando configurar una tarea en CRON mediante el uso de la linea de comandos Linux bash que he instalado hace poco. Soy nuevo utilizando entornos Linux.

La idea es que un script escrito en R se ejecute regularmente según la fecha indicada.

El archivo de R se llama `Twitter_collect_analyse.R`y cuando lo ejecuto funciona perfectamente.

La línea de código que estoy escribiendo para configurar la tarea es la siguiente:
[image]

Nota: el archivo de R se encuentra en un directorio de Windows.

Ahora, cuando se debería estar ejecutando la tarea, parece que no funciona. Esto lo verifico así a la hora programada:

```
service cron status

> * cron is not running
```

Agradezco si me podéis ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
service cron start
```

Debería comenzar el servicio cron

Haz el siguiente para comenzar el servicio cron al iniciar Windows
https://blog.snowme34.com/post/schedule-tasks-using-crontab-on-windows-10-with-wsl/index.html#Make-the-Daemon-start-at-Windows-Boot